# download multiple attachments from Website as image in python

Tags: python

I was previously using the below code to retrieve the url image from website.

```
imagelist = []
for element in ele.find_elements_by_tag_name('a'):
    if 'vault' in element.get_attribute('href'):
        imagelist.append(str(element.get_attribute('href')))
        c = 1
        for image in imagelist:
            request.urlretrieve(image, str(directory) + '\\' + 'picture' '.jpg')
            c = c + 1
```

However now the the images are not getting stored through vault and it is now causing issues. it is currently using AAA.com/relate-file.cgi?retrieve_file=0421935666_1576295757_DSCF4159.JPG

How do I modify the code as I couldn't understand how to proceed.  I used AAA.com since I couldn't use my organization's website here. Also I need to download all the images from website and the count could vary each time.

Comment: The name of your organisation is still visible. CGI?

Comment: This seems broad. You’re probably better off reading some guides and tutorials on web scraping, which is outside the realm of Stack Overflow.

Comment: @NicolasGervais No its not CGI, Its the path the images are currently loaded onto. Its been changed recently to this path.

Comment: @Amc I just started learning python 3 weeks back, Im very new to this field and i am having hard time finding the right details that's y posted my query here. It would be great if you could give me some pointers so that i can proceed.

Comment: @SriniVasan What do you mean by _right details_?

Comment: @AMC i checked out many tutorials and guides and they provide scraping the images from pre-defined path. In my case i cannot confirm how many attachment are at website each time since its based on issue type. The above code which i used was working fine to retrieve all the images until now. However since the upload path was changed i am unable to find the details. If you could help me or point me in right direction, It would really help me out.

Comment: @SriniVasan Which _upload path_ are you referring to?

Comment: @AMC previously it was uploaded to - www.AAA.com/Vault/0421935666_1576295757_DSCF4159.JPG, So i used the above coding to find the vault in href and download the image. But now its using - www.AAA.com/relate-file.cgi?retrieve_file=0421935666_1576295757_DSCF4159.JPG

Comment: i tried using the below,

Comment: if 'relate-file.cgi' in element.get_attribute('href'):
         imagelist.append(str(element.get_attribute('href'))) but its showing timeout error